# Access query to retrieve all three fields not equal

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I need to write a query in MS Access where all the three columns should not be equal .

For example there are three columns A B C . Each column should not be equal to each other all should have a separate value.

How can I write such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   my_table
WHERE  a<>b AND a<>c AND b<>c
```

Comment: Im getting C=A when i do this Query

Comment: The `where` clause explicitly states `a<>c`. Do you have `null`s in `a` or `c`? Also, are these columns strings? Is it possible that one contains whitespaces so that they aren't in fact equal, but may appear equal to the naked eye?

Answer (score 2):

If your fields are non-nullable, all you need to check is that A != B, A != C, and B != C:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE A <> B AND A <> C AND B <> C
```

The same query would be OK if fields are nullable, but `NULL`s are not considered a valid value.

Comment: Im getting C=A when i do this Query

Comment: That is not possible - the query explicitly requires them to be non-equal. If C and A are strings, they might look like equal when they differ only by trailing whitespace in one of the strings.